# Regex to remove stop-words between two words

Tags: java, regex, stop-words

I have a set of words named "stopwords". Now i need to match two words but between these words can appear a space or a words in the set "stopwords",for e.g. "power energy", "power of energy", "power for energy", "power of the energy". 
In the stopwords set there are also "for, of, the, ..."

I want to obtain "power energy" without stopwords. Is it possible?

Comment: not clear but what i guess you want to search a word between to words ..???

Comment: Not very much clear, can you give the example telling which are the i/p and which are o/p ?

Comment: do you want to remove stopwords from the text?

Comment: yes, i want to remove stopwords

Comment: I updated my answer to remove all words in between first and last word

Answer (score 1):

Finding the the substring will work. This will format any phrase in the form

> **Word (stopwords)+ Endword** to **Word Endword**

```
 String power = "power of energy";
 String[] toks = power.split("[\\s]+"); // in case of extra space between words.

 String removed = 
        power.substring(power.indexOf(toks[0]), power.indexOf(toks[0])
                                                    + toks[0].length())
        + " " + power.substring(power.indexOf(toks[toks.length - 1]), power.indexOf(toks[toks.length - 1 ]) 
                                                    + toks[toks.length - 1].length());

System.out.println(removed);
```

> Output: **power energy**

**Method**

```
public static String removeStopWord(String phrase){
    String[] toks = phrase.split("[\\s]+");

    String removed = 
        phrase.substring(phrase.indexOf(toks[0]), phrase.indexOf(toks[0])
                                                    + toks[0].length())
        + " " + phrase.substring(phrase.indexOf(toks[toks.length - 1]), phrase.indexOf(toks[toks.length - 1]) 
                                                    + toks[toks.length - 1].length());
    return removed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple replaceAll() of java  would do the trick :)

```
public class Replace {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String s="power of the world";
s=s.replaceAll("of|the|", "");
s=s.replaceAll("( )+", " ");
System.out.println(s);
}
}
```